# Unable to implement Title-Adding Script in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have essentially zero coding knowledge and only a basic understanding of Google sheets - so here is my problem:

I just want to automatically add the File Name / Sheet title into each sheet to be printed. I found a script supposedly to do so which is as follows:

```
function onOpen(e)
{
    e.source.getRange('Sheet1!B2').setValue(e.source.getName())
}
```

I've tried to add this to Google Sheets and just get error after error. It seems to want to call upon a cell for some reason and - in general does nothing. Sometimes I get the "NAME?" error code, other times it's just blank.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Unclear as to what I'm doing wrong, I assumed that this would be some easy function to add but I'm missing part of the ritual.

Comment: Just to confirm your goal, would you like to get the spreadsheet title each time you open that certain file? As that is how [onOpen](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onopene) trigger works.

Comment: That's correct. I would like to be able to have the title automatically generated in the sheet - so that when printed it's present. (Normally the title is simply the day's date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Recommendation: Populate Google Sheets Title in a cell when opening**

```
function onOpen(e) { 


var sheet = e.source.getSheets();

 sheet.forEach(x => {

x.getRange('B2').setValue(e.source.getName())

}) }
```

Note: After saving the script above, reload the file or close and open the file again to populate the Sheets title. The title will populate in Cell B2 depends on which sheet tab is active.

[image: gettitle]

Comment: Thank you for all the work on your end, it really is great! However, I still seem to be getting nothing. I consider that I'm just not adding the script correctly.

Comment: As an update: I can get other scripts to work. Even other OnOpen scripts seem to work fine. But both your version and my version of the Title importing script do not.

Answer (score 0):

I just started deleting parts and then it worked. I'll post the corrected code - as you can see (and you can probably word this better yourself), I think I was like... double calling a function? Or setting it up to be called in a particular way instead of the on-open way.

Either way, this works. Just put it in the Apps Script, Save it, you're good. It ***will*** throw an error if you try to run it in the Apps Script editor. This is fine, it's (apparently) supposed to.

[image]

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.